# I am unable to deploy my LWC component from Visual studio code

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am unable to deploy my lwc component from vscode. Showing Following Error
=== Deploy Errors
PROJECT PATH  ERRORS
LWC1513: @salesforce/apex modules only support default imports.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import {getProcessNodesList} from 
'@salesforce/apex/ProcessNodesController.getProcessNodes';

export default class DisplayProcessNodes extends LightningElement 
{
   @track steps=[];   
   @track error;   

   @wire(getProcessNodesList)
   wiredProcessNodes({ error, data }) {
        if (data) 
        {   
            var count = 1;
            for(pn in data)
            {
                this.steps.push({label:pn, value:count.toString()});
                count++;
            } 
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.steps = undefined;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to perform an apex import, remove the brackets from around getProcessNodesList and the error should be resolved. When importing apex methods you need to do them one per line, and without any brackets; those are reserved for multiple imports. So your code will look like this

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getProcessNodesList from 
'@salesforce/apex/ProcessNodesController.getProcessNodes';

 export default class DisplayProcessNodes extends LightningElement 
 {
   @track steps=[];   
   @track error;   

   @wire(getProcessNodesList)
   wiredProcessNodes({ error, data }) {
       if (data) 
       {   
           var count = 1;
           for(pn in data)
           {
            this.steps.push({label:pn, value:count.toString()});
            count++;
        } 
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.steps = undefined;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution it worked